# Publish multiple result from LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher() inside RxJava nested chain

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-livedata, android-viewmodel, mutablelivedata

Let's start with a basic sample,

Suppose I have the follow code block for getting an ***Auth Token*** from the **Repository**

```
private fun getToken(): LiveData<TokenResponse> {
        return LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(remoteSource.getAuthToken()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .map { token -> token }
        )
    }
```

I'm receiving the **LiveData** result in **ViewModel**

```
class HomeModel {

        private var tokenLiveDataSource: MediatorLiveData<TokenResponse> = MediatorLiveData()
        private var tokenLiveData: MutableLiveData<TokenResponse> = MutableLiveData()

        fun observeTokenLiveData(): LiveData<TokenResponse> {
            return tokenLiveData
        }

        fun getToken() {
            val source = repository.getToken()
            tokenLiveDataSource.addSource(source) {
                tokenLiveData.value = it
                tokenLiveDataSource.removeSource(source)
            }
        }
    }
```

At this point everything works perfectly as excepted. However the problem arrives when I want to merge 2 request together and get separate **LiveData** for each of them. Let's say I want to call the **Search API** after receiving the result from **Token API**. My objective is to get 2 **LiveData** event changes for each step. The modified code to demonstrate my requirements is given below,

```
private fun getSearchResult(): LiveData<?> {
    return LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(remoteSource.getAuthToken() // 1ST API CALL
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map { token ->
                // NOTIFY THE 1ST API RESULT/RETURN LiveData<TokenResponse>
                token
            }
            .flatMap { token ->
                remoteSource.getSearchResult(token) // 2ND API CALL
            }
            .map { results ->
                // NOTIFY THE 2ND API RESULT/RETURN LiveData<SearchResult>
                results
            }

    )
}
```

How to receive 2 LiveData from the given example?

```
class HomeModel {

            private var tokenLiveDataSource: MediatorLiveData<TokenResponse> = MediatorLiveData()
            private var tokenLiveData: MutableLiveData<TokenResponse> = MutableLiveData()

            private var searchLiveDataSource: MediatorLiveData<SearchResponse> = MediatorLiveData()
            private var searchLiveData: MutableLiveData<SearchResponse> = MutableLiveData()

            fun observeTokenLiveData(): LiveData<TokenResponse> {
                return tokenLiveData
            }

            fun observeSearchLiveData(): LiveData<SearchResponse> {
                return searchLiveData
            }

            fun getSearchResult() {
                // RECEIVE 2 LiveData HERE
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a wrapper class that can have both token and the search result

```
data class TokenAndSearchResult(
    val tokenResponse: TokenResponse,
    val searchResponse: SearchResponse
)
```

Then the repository:

```
private fun getSearchResult(): LiveData<TokenAndSearchResult> {
    return LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(remoteSource.getAuthToken()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            // .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) probably won't be needed. LiveData is observed in the main thread anyway.
            .flatMap { token ->
                remoteSource.getSearchResult(token) // Flowable<SearchResult>
                    .map { result -> TokenAndSearchResult(token, result) } // Flowable<TokenAndSearchResult>
                    .startWith(TokenAndSearchResult(token, SearchResult()))) // Flowable<TokenAndSearchResult>
            } // Flowable<TokenAndSearchResult>

    )
}
```

The resulting `LiveData<TokenAndSearchResult>` will emit one instance of `TokenAndSearchResult` with the token. This initial instance will have an empty search result, represented by `SearchResult()` in above code example.

Once `remoteSource.getSearchResult()` returns, it will emit for the second time with non-empty `SearchResult` value.

ViewModel can map this result `LiveData` to individual `LiveData`

```
class HomeModel {

    // Declaring "var LiveData" is usually an anti-pattern, because
    // LiveData shouldn't change but only the object wrapped by LiveData
    // should change.
    private val tokenLiveData = MediatorLiveData<TokenResponse>() 
    private val searchLiveData = MediatorLiveData<SearchResponse>()

    fun observeTokenLiveData(): LiveData<TokenResponse> {
        return tokenLiveData
    }

    fun observeSearchLiveData(): LiveData<SearchResponse> {
        return searchLiveData
    }

    fun getSearchResult() {
        val source = repository.getSearchResult()
        tokenLiveData.addSource(source) {
            tokenLiveData.value = it.tokenResponse
            tokenLiveData.removeSource(source)
        }
        searchLiveData.addSource(source) {
            searchLiveData.value = it.searchResponse
            searchLiveData.removeSource(source)
        }
    }
}
```

Additional thought:

Once the app completes an authentication process and obtains an authentication token, app normally wants to persist that authentication token and not to repeat that authentication process until the token expires. Also it should have a logic that detects 401 or 403 authentication error and retries after refreshing the token.